# React- Router, making sense of the transitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, flux

I've used Angular and Flask and I've worked with routing and transitions but there is something confusing about how React-Router works.

For example from the introduction page https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md :

```
React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
        {/* Add the route, nested where we want the UI to nest */}
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

The way this code nests makes it hard for me to look at this and tell you what is going to render based on the URL path we are currently at.

Like for instance is the "/" portion always going to render or just when we are at the top level endpoint?

Does "about" and "inbox render together or is it an either/or scenario?

Sorry if this is extremely obvious to some. It's had me a bit tripped up for way too long now so I wanted to ask you guys. :)

Answer (score 3):

Given the following `App` component:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>App title</h1>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Hitting `/` renders that component, and the `this.props.children` is `undefined`.

Hitting `/about`, the router first parses `/`, so the `App` component is rendered again, as before.

From there, the router drills down the routes hierarchy, to see if there's any path matching with the rest of the string i.e `about`. And there is:

`<Route path="about" component={About} />`

This route is a direct child of `App`, so `this.props.children` is now the `About` component, which will be rendered since we chose to render `this.props.children` in `App`.

Comment: Does that mean that "/" is always rendered then? Does that mean the URL should either be "....../inbox" or  "....../about"? Also does it mean that every time "....../about" is requested then the URL should also have ......./about/#/user/13425 so that I can find the correct user data to populate a "Message" component as well?

Comment: 1) yes 2) not sure what you mean but you can't request `/inbox` and `/about` at the same time 3) defining `id` as a parameter in your route as such: `messages/:id` allows to retrieve the corresponding value with `this.props.params.id` from `Message` if you request `/about/user/13425`. Requesting `/about` without parameters will not render `Message` because `this.props.children` in the `About` component will be `undefined`.